# I can't submit my Flask-wtf Form which contains SelectField and SelectMultipleField

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

Here is my FlaskForm class;

```
class LookUpPartsForm(FlaskForm):
    year = SelectField("Year", choices=[('select year', '-- Select Year --')], validators=[InputRequired()])
    make = SelectField("Make", choices=[('select make', '-- Select Make --')], validators=[InputRequired()])
    model = SelectField("Model", choices=[('select model', '-- Select Model --')],validators=[InputRequired()])
    engine = SelectField("Engine", choices=[('select engine', '-- Select Engine --')],validators=[InputRequired()])
    category = SelectField("Category", choices=[('select category', '-- Select Category --')], validators=[InputRequired()])
    group = SelectMultipleField("Group", choices=[('select groups', '-- Select Category to see Groups --')], validators=[InputRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Look Up Part')
```

Here is how I setup every form field;

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.year.label(class="form-control-label")}}
    {% if form.year.errors %}
        {{ form.year(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {% for error in form.year.error %}
                <span>{{error}}</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
        {{ form.year(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

this is the function i use;

```
@lookup_parts_bp.route('/lookup_parts/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def lookup_parts():
    form = LookUpPartsForm()
    form.year.choices = [('select year', '-- Select Year --')]
    for year in open_cbk_data().keys():
        form.year.choices.append((year, year))

    cbk_category_group_json = open_parts_lookup_categories_and_groups()
    form.category.choices = [('-- select category --', '-- Select Category --')]
    for key in cbk_category_group_json.get('Categories').keys():
        form.category.choices.append((cbk_category_group_json['Categories'][key]['code'], key))

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return f'''<h1>{form.year.data}</h1>
                    <h1>{form.make.data}</h1>
                    <h1>{form.model.data}</h1>
                    <h1>{form.engine.data}</h1>'''
    return render_template('lookup_parts.html', form=form)
```

Every field starts with "Select Year", "Select Make" etc. When i just submit without choosing anything for example year SelectField is "Select Year" and make SelectField is "Select Make" etc. It works fine I can see these data but when I choose year make model etc. I got red exclamation mark for every field and can't submit. It doesn't say Input required. I only see red exclamation mark next to dropdown list.

I am getting 'Not a valid choice' error even though I am choosing element from every SelectField.

Comment: I don't like `choices = [('select year', '-- Select Year --')]` - probably `Flask` also checks if selected value match to `[('select year', '-- Select Year --')]`  and it gives error.

Comment: I don't know why but when I used  `request.method == 'POST'` instead of `if form.validate_on_submit():`, it worked perfectly fine. I still appreciate any answer to this question if possible.

Comment: using `request.method == 'POST'` you check only if you get `Form` (and as for me you should do it always) but it doesn't validate values in form - and when you use `form.validate_on_submit()` it check if values are correct  and it probably compare it with values in `choices = [('select year', '-- Select Year --')]` and it makes problem. You may have to add to `choices = [('select year', '-- Select Year --')]` other values - and you may have to do it inside `LookUpPartsForm`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.In my case make, model, engine etc. SelectFields changes according to year SelectField so i don't know how am i going to change the choices inside LookUpPartsForm. I tried with empty choices list but i am still getting same error.

Comment: maybe use `print()` to see what you have in `choices` and `cbk_category_group_json` - maybe when you create form then it you have all values in `choices` but when you validate it then it has empty `choices`

Comment: BTW: inside `LookUpPartsForm` you can create `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): ....` to fill choices.